# egit marks files as dirty after switching branch

Tags: eclipse, egit

When I switch from one branch to another, Eclipse marks some files (I don't known the criteria) as dirty (with an *).

When checking out from console all works ok.

I have tried set core.filemode to false, with no luck.

The only way to solve the problem is doing git reset HEAD filenames in console.

Is there a way that Egit don't do this?

Egit vers. 1.2.0.201112221903-r

Comment: What do you see when you look for changes in the files shown as having changed?

Comment: Nothing. Also in console. It's says that is modified by git diff says nothing. I think that could be something about the permissions (we run in windows).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to reproduce this using a newer EGit from the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly)?

There was a problem when the mode (permissions) of a file changed, which was fixed some time ago.